# how do I view recursive menu items from Array of Array data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, cakephp

I am trying to view dynamic menu into my application. I made my policy that I will have a table and I will add menu items by myself into the table. I have a table `Menu_Panel` like this:

```
id   menu_name    parent_menu_id
1    root         0
4    user         1
5    sales        1
6    user-list    2
```

For nested items I made a query and Then I executed the query which outputs are below:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [menu_name] => root
        [parent_menu_id] => 0
        [sub-menu] => Array
            (
                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4
                        [menu_name] => user
                        [parent_menu_id] => 1
                        [sub-menu] => Array
                            (
                                [6] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 6
                                        [menu_name] => user-list
                                        [parent_menu_id] => 2
                                    )


                            )

                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 5
                        [menu_name] => Sales
                        [parent_menu_id] => 1
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Now I think, I got my desired result cause it looks like nested. Now I want to show this recursive menu items in ul->li into my view page. Here is my code: I kept the result into `$side_bar_menu`::

```
@foreach($side_bar_menu as $module)
            <li class="mm-dropdown">

                <a href="#"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-columns"></i><span class="mm-text">User </span></a>
                <ul>
                @foreach($module['sub-menu'] as $sub_module)
                    <li>
                        <a tabindex="-1" href="{{route('menu-panel')}}"><span class="mm-text">Menu Panel</span></a>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
                </ul>
            </li>
            @endforeach
```

I think I miss something in foreach. in this case `$module['sub-menu']` is not working. As I noticed that array indexing number are not sequential.

My question is that how may I view the item lists in my view file in php ?

Comment: Wait what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @TimOgilvy  :: I got the answer in below. I want to view nested menu items with li -> ul -> li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use `foreach` from root level. Here is the view code you may try:

```
@if($side_bar_menu)
    <?php //print_r($side_bar_menu); exit(); ?>
    @foreach($side_bar_menu as $module)
            @foreach($module['sub-menu'] as $sub_module)
            <?php // print_r($sub_module['menu_name']);  ?>
                <li class="mm-dropdown">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="{{route('menu-panel')}}"><span class="mm-text">{{$sub_module['menu_name']}}</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        @foreach($sub_module['sub-menu'] as $sub_sub_module)
                        <?php // print_r($sub_sub_module['menu_name']);  ?>
                            <li>
                                <a tabindex="-1" href="{{route('menu-panel')}}"><span class="mm-text">{{$sub_sub_module['menu_name']}}</span></a>
                            </li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </li>
            @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

I hope this will work. Please let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks, at a glance like you are trying to treat a sequential array as an associative array. I'm not familiar with the cake/laravel markup you are using however.  In vanilla PHP you would treat it like this:

```
foreach ($module as $moduleIndex => $menuModule) {

    // Do top level stuff here using $menuModule
    $subMenu = $menuModule['sub-menu'];

    foreach ($subMenu as $smIndex => $subItem) {

        // Do submenu stuff here using $subItem

       renderSubmenuItems($subItem);

    }
}
```

Not sure if this will help, but have a look into handling associative vs sequential arrays. Hopefully you will find your issue.

Comment: :: Its also a great solution. We can make items from our method instead of view page. I really like this one.

Comment: @SelimReza I have to confess I dislike templating engines when they tempt me away from using OOP to solve problems.  But I am also showing my ignorance of Cake and Laravel

Comment: :: Indeed. would you please elaborate little more so that I would earn some knowledge.